# md-select change value from javascript dom

Tags: dom, angular-material

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Material Library -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js">

<input id='a' ng-model="a">
      <md-input-container>
     <label>select</label>
     <md-select ng-model="a">
      <md-option value="1">11</md-option>
      <md-option value="2">22</md-option>
      <md-option value="3">33</md-option>
     </md-select>
      </md-input-container>
```

I want to set value of input to change value of md-select

I want to use only this

```
document.getElementById('a').value="2";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the element by "id" you need to make sure to set the "id" attribute

```
<md-select id="a" ng-model="a">
```

But it is recommended (and easier) you change it using

```
$scope.a = 2
```